# How do I keep keyboard focus on a single component?

Tags: java, swing, focus

I need to keep keyboard input focus on a single component inside a JPanel. It's for an application with a on-screen-keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I really understand the question. But you can try something like:

```
otherComponents.setFocusable( false );
```

You also might need to use a custom [FocusTraversalPolicy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

If you need more help then post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I want to freeze focus on a specific component. Not let the others steal it. What is unclear here? Having to explicitly setFocusable on all other components doesn't look nice.

Comment: Maybe explicitly preventing focus on other component is a little more work but it will look nicer. Using a FocusListener may be easer, but the user might complain about a "flicker" when the user tabs to another component before focus is returned to the original component.

Comment: Can't tab without a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You better put the focus back to the component (`component.grabFocus()`) after pressing a button on the on-screen keyboard.

Or you could set focus listener (`component.addFocusListener(FocusListener l)`) and never let go of the focus by calling grabFocus() in the `focusLost()` method of `FocusListener`.

Comment: Please don't recommend the grabFocus() method. According to the API the requestFocusInWindow() method should be used.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you focus on your **singleComponent** when opening your Frame, without having to change the focus policy of enything else: `singleComponent.requestFocusInWindow();` Since the focus will not freeze, you will need to setFocusable(false) for the other components like camicr suggests.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess: take a look at the [`InputVerifier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).